# How to run nmake in one bat file

Tags: batch-file, nmake

When I run the following commands one by one in windows command prompt, they work fine.

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\gdal_win32_develop\\workspace\\codes\\deps\\gdal\\gdal_1.8_rtc
nmake -f makefile.vc clean
nmake -f makefile.vc
```

When I write them into one bat file and try to execute the bat file in windows command prompt, it only output the first command, the left three commands are not executed.

How to do this? I need this because I want to run it in one Jenkins build project.

Comment: How are you detecting the other 3 don't get executed?

Comment: I am not sure, there is no more output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace line `%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""` with

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

You are not aware of it but while typing commands in command line, after first, you got a new instance of cmd.exe and next commands are typed in this new instance. You will need two `EXIT` commands to exit command prompt.

Typing commands, you could just type `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` instead of `%COMSPEC% ...`, but in batch it would break batch execution, so you have to prepend `CALL`.

Comment: I read this article 
http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.com/2011/10/nmake-and-its-environment.html
Learned a lot and figure it out myself. But I think your answer is much easier for many newers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `%comspec% /c ...`, not `%comspec% /k`. Look at `cmd /?` for more help. Moreover, you don't need double backslashes, one is enough.

Comment: I tried /c instead of /k. But still got 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Getting nmake not recognised suggests it tries the next steps. Does putting the cd blah blah blah in quote cd "C:\\..." make a difference?